# ggsave() does not bolden text, and it changes font of all text instead of just plot title

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, showtext, extrafont

I'm making a chart in ggplot2 and `ggsave()` does not do what I expect.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(showtext)

showtext_auto()
hedFont <- "Pragati Narrow"
font_add_google(
  name = hedFont,
  family = hedFont,
  regular.wt = 400,
  bold.wt = 700
)

chart <- ggplot(
  data = cars,
  aes(
    x = speed,
    y = dist
  )
) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "Here is a title",
    subtitle = "Subtitle here"
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(
      size = 20,
      family = hedFont,
      face = "bold"
    ),
    axis.title = element_text(
      face = "bold"
    )
  )

ggsave(
  filename = "myplot",
  plot = chart,
  device = "png",
  path = "~/Desktop",
  width = 300,
  height = 200,
  units = "mm",
  dpi = 72
)
```

What I expected was for the chart's title to have the custom font. Instead, `ggsave()` makes a chart where all the text has the font. I expected the axis titles to be bold, but they are not.

Here's what I see in RStudio viewer when I run the `ggplot()` code in it.

[image]

Here's what `ggsave()` produces.

[image]

I want `ggsave()` to make a chart where only the chart's title has the font and the axes' titles are bold.

**UPDATE**: I tried Tung's suggestion. I downloaded the Google Font onto my computer. Here's my new code.

```
font_import(
  paths = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts/",
  recursive = T,
  prompt = F,
  pattern = "Pragati"
)
loadfonts(device = "pdf")
loadfonts(device = "postscript")

myFont <- "Pragati Narrow"

chart <- ggplot(
  data = cars,
  aes(
    x = speed,
    y = dist
  )
) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "Here is a title",
    subtitle = "Subtitle here"
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(
      size = 20,
      family = myFont,
      face = "bold"
    ),
    axis.title = element_text(
      face = "bold"
    )
  )

ggsave(
  filename = "myplot2.png",
  plot = chart,
  device = "png",
  path = "~/Desktop",
  width = 300,
  height = 200,
  units = "mm",
  dpi = 72
)
```

Doesn't seem to have changed anything.

[image]

I don't see any errors or warnings in the RStudio console either.

Comment: `showtext` doesn't work well with RStudio graphic devices https://github.com/yixuan/showtext/issues/7

Comment: Can you download "Pragati Narrow" font and try the `extrafont` package instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888677/

Comment: @Tung Thanks. I did notice RStudio's viewer doesn't work well with `showtext`. But would downloading "Pragmati Narrow" change the output of `ggsave()`? I'm also not sure how to install that font on my computer. I'm using Debian 9.3

Comment: it should work. Follow the steps in the answer that I linked above. I tested it before for both Windows and Linux

Comment: @Tung Updated. I don't see a difference, but I've probably done something incorrect.

Comment: see my answer for a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked on my Linux Mint Rosa machine. You need to download and import the desired font to `extrafont` database per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888677/786542)

```
library(extrafont)
library(ggplot2)

hedFont <- "BitstreamVeraSansMono"

chart <- ggplot(
  data = cars,
  aes(
    x = speed,
    y = dist
  )
) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "Here is a title",
    subtitle = "Subtitle here"
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(
      size = 20,
      family = hedFont,
      face = "bold"
    ),
    axis.title = element_text(
      face = "bold"
    )
  )
chart

ggsave(
  filename = "./output/myplot.png",
  plot = chart,
  type = "cairo",
  height = 4,
  width = 6,
  dpi = 150)
```

[image]

Comment: Also relevant https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2017/09/27/working-with-r-cairo-graphics-custom-fonts-and-ggplot/

Comment: When I replace "BitstreamVeraSansMono" with "Pragati Narrow", it works fine. Actually, when I reran the code I posted in the "update," the charts came out correctly. I suspect restarting RStudio had something to do with this...

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem using the `extrafont` package, where the font I specified would show in the RStudio viewer but change when I saved as a `.png` with `ggsave()`. Neither of the above answers worked for me (font was already saved in my `extrafont` database and specifying the `base_family` didn't work).

I was able to get it working simply by uninstalling the `ragg` package using `installr::uninstall.packages("ragg")`.

I don't know why this works, if anyone has any explanations for this I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: FWIW this also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here I also give the showtext solution.

**Short version**: add `theme_grey(base_family = "sans")` to the `ggplot` statement, and below is the output as expected.

```
chart <- ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = "Here is a title", subtitle = "Subtitle here") +
    theme_grey(base_family = "sans") +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(
            size = 20,
            family = hedFont,
            face = "bold"
        ),
        axis.title = element_text(
            face = "bold"
        )
    )
```

[image]

**Long version**: when the base family is not specified in `ggplot`, `showtext` uses the "WenQuanYi MicroHei" font family as the default, in order to support CJK characters. However, this family has no bold font face, so in your original code the axis title was displayed in a regular font face. I would suggest always setting `par(family = "sans")` in base plots and `theme_grey(base_family = "sans")` in `ggplot` plots.

As a side note, it does not mean that `showtext` cannot be used inside RStudio. You can call `x11()` or the alike to open a window and `showtext` should work well with it.