# Numbers in parentheses are not centered in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom-text

Numbers are top justified with parentheses in `geom_label_repel()` (Example with code below). The same behavior occurs when using `geom_label()`. How can I get the numbers in the labels to be in the center of the parenthesis?

[image: Example plot with geom_label_repel() (code above) showing issue]

```
library(tidyverse)
df_cars<- 
  mtcars[2:6,] %>% 
    mutate(CarName = rownames(.),
           CarCyl = paste(CarName, " (",cyl,")",sep = ""))

ggplot(df_cars,aes(mpg,hp))+
  geom_point()+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label = CarCyl))+
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 3):

Update after clarification (removed first answer):

According to this answer [Fonts not available in R after importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072340/fonts-not-available-in-r-after-importing).
We could set the Graphic Device for RStudio to AGG:

`Tools > Global options > General > Graphics > Backend: AGG`

[image]

```
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df_cars,aes(mpg,hp))+
  geom_point()+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label = CarCyl))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn’t help. The numbers still appear to be top justified in the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Would your solution influence other behavior in R?

Comment: I am not sure. But if you encounter any problems you can set back to default.