# Specific fonts in ggplot2 not saving to pdf error

Tags: r, ggplot2, extrafont

I'm trying to save multiple plots to one pdf, typically I use:

```
# creating pdf from four panels
# these aren't reproducible but any ggplot will recreate error essentially
pdf(file = "Fig.1", height = 14, width = 14)
Fig.1<- grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4)

print(Fig.1)
dev.off()
```

However, I want to use a specific font in the plots.

I have thus downloaded and installed the `fontextra`package, intalled and loaded the fonts with `loadfonts(device = "win")`.  I then use `theme(text=element_text(family="Calibri"))` within the ggplot call.
When I re-run code individual plots will look fine in R itself. I can also successfully use grid.arrange using `gridExtra` to arrange them and check them within R itself. However, when I use:

```
pdf(file = "Fig.4.trw.pdf", height = 14, width = 14)
Fig.4.trw<- grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

I get a bunch of errors associated to fonts:

```
In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
font width unknown for character 0x30
```

I've also tried to use `ggsave` but that isn't working either, please help!

Thanks

Comment: You probably need `loadfonts(device = "all")` or `"pdf", "postscript"`

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888677/786542 or try [showtext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906008/786542)

Comment: Have tried, it is throwing exactly same errors.

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Did the font show up when you run either `font_families()` or `windowsFonts()`?

Comment: Yeah it comes up. Weird thing is the plot looks fine before I actually try to save it to PDF. Ok I have managed a workaround that seems to function, I found it scouring the internet. If you use this: `ggsave("Fig1.pdf", Fig.1, width=14, 
    height=14,device=cairo_pdf)` it seems to work.

Comment: The syntax you used is in one of the link I posted