# Verify font availability in R

Tags: r, ggtext

I have a font installed on my OS, so this code runs fine:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(extrafont)
iris %>% ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
theme(
  text = element_text(family = "Metropolis")
)
```

Let's force an error (note that I wrote "metropolis", not "Metropolis"):

```
iris %>% ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
theme(
  text = element_text(family = "metropolis")
)
```

That gives me an error, which is ok because font "metropolis" doesn't exist.

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
```

Is there a way where I can verify before if certain font is installed, in R? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already using the `extrafont` package so you can use `fonts()` to see the registered fonts.  To check if a particular font is available you can do:

```
library(extrafont)

"metropolis" %in% fonts()

[1] FALSE
```

Comment: When I tried `"Metropolis" %in% fonts()`it gave me `FALSE`. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Additional fonts need to be registered with `font_import()` before they're available.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251290/add-font-to-r-that-is-not-in-extrafonts-library

Comment: Realized that `fonts()`only shows ttf fonts. Now it works. Thank you.