# Fonts not loading in showtext font_add_google

Tags: r, ggplot2, showtext

I'm trying to graph some data and my code looks like this:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('tidyr')
library('ggthemes')
library('showtext')

font_add_google('Syncopate', 'Syncopate')
showtext_auto()

ggplot(aes(x = X, group=1), data = glassdoor)+
  geom_line(aes(y = col1, color = 'red'))+
  geom_line(aes(y = col2, color = 'blue'))+
  geom_line(aes(y = col3, color = 'magenta'))+
  geom_line(aes(y = col4, color = 'yellow'))+
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Syncopate"))+
  ggtitle('A Long Test Title')
```

Syncopate is a distinctive font, seen [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Syncopate?selection.family=Syncopate). But my visualization's font just looks like this (this is a test graph, ignore its overall poorness):

[image]

But if I load a system theme like Times New Roman, it works fine. Why aren't my google fonts loading using showtext?

**Edit**

Jrakru's answer works, but bear in mind that you have to run that entire code block: The new fonts will appear in a saved png file, but not in the preview window. This isn't written as a slight against the answer, but rather for others like myself who expect the fonts to show up in the RStudio console and therefore omit the `ggsave` and `png` portions of the code.

Comment: try loading the `ggplot2` library after you defined your fonts

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906008/

Comment: @Jrakru56 that's doesn't seem to be working either :( unless i'm misunderstanding what you mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GitHub for `showtext` mentions

> This example should work on most graphics devices, including pdf(),
>   png(), postscript(), and on-screen devices such as windows() on
>   Windows and x11() on Linux.

If you read *really really hard* between lines, that means, that `RStudioGD` graphics device is not supported.  I did not see that the first few times I read it. I only know because the `vignette` is a little more explicit.

> NOTE: Currently showtext does not work with the built-in graphics
>   device of RStudio, hence to try the code below, it is suggested to run
>   the code in original R console, or use other graphics devices such as
>   x11() and  windows()

see 
https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html

With the above knowledge, we can do this:

```
library('tidyr')
library('ggthemes')
library('showtext')

font_add_google("Schoolbell", "bell")
showtext_auto()

library('ggplot2')

df<- data.frame(x=1:10, y=101:110)

options("device" = "windows")

win.graph(10,10,12)

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x,y))+
  theme(text = element_text(family = "bell"))+
  ggtitle('A Long Test Title')


ggsave("showtext-example.png", width = 7, height = 4, dpi = 96)

options("device" = "RStudioGD")
```

And Voila!
[image]

Ps: I assumed you are a `windows` user.

Comment: You mean `x11` should work in defining the device in options? I tried that and it didn't seem to work :(

Comment: Are you on a MacOS? If yes, I think that you guys use `quartz`.

Comment: On Ubuntu. It's still not working for me when changing to x11

Comment: No it's just producing the same visualization I created in my question :(

Comment: It might be worth creating an issue on the `showtext` github.  Is the `png()` and `ggsave()` not working etiher?

Comment: Hmmm...the png() and ggsave() seem to be working actually, but it's not working in the preview window, which was as far as I was going. I'm gonna mark this question as solved but I'll put a note in my question that the answer only works for the saved file. Thanks a bunch for your help and sorry for the confusion/not following the entire answer.

Answer (score 4):

according to the same document: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html

And the very bottom of it, you can read this:

> Compatibility with RStudio
>
> Starting from version 0.9, showtext can work well with the RStudio
> graphics device (RStudioGD). Simply call showtext_auto() in the
> RStudio session and then the plots will be displayed correctly.

it worked for me in RStudio 1.3.959