# ggplot2 legend title not respecting bold for Google Font

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, showtext

Not sure why, but when I import "Montserrat" font with showtext::font_add_google, the legend title will not be bold :/

```
require(showtext);require(ggplot2)

font_add_google(name="Montserrat")
ggplot(mpg,aes(cty,hwy,fill=manufacturer))+geom_point()+
theme(text=element_text(family="Montserrat"),legend.title=element_text(face="bold"))
```

[image]

I think this (partially) works (though no bolding) because I have Montserrat installed locally. If I try a font I haven't installed, i.e. with: `font_add_google(name="Yesteryear")`

I get this error and no plot:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
In addition: Warning message:
In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "Yesteryear"
```

Comment: On my machine no error pops up. But I got the same warnings which can be solved by adding `showtext_auto()
options("device" = "windows")
win.graph(10,10,12)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219980/fonts-not-loading-in-showtext-font-add-google

Comment: hmm...I am a Mac user. I've tried using quartz(), with inconsistent results. Sometimes it renders a font as expected. Mostly it renders nothing. But I've never gotten it to bold the legend title, as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Stefan, adding `showtext_auto()` before plotting works. It does not render correctly in R Studio (under Mac OS Catalina), but it does output bolded legend upon `ggsave()`[image]