# Change the font of a graph with interact_plot (package interactions)

Tags: r, graph, fonts

I am trying to graph a 2-way interaction using `interact_plot` function in `interactions`. How do I change the font size to Times New Roman?

Here is my code:

```
interact_plot(Interac2, pred = SA, modx = RPF, alpha = .05, legend.main = "RP", x.label = "EXB", y.label = "NORCA")
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I noticed that you mentioned `interact_plot` in `jtools`. The documentation there says that this function has been deprecated and moved to package `interactions` (which I also edited into your question). Looking at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/jacob-long/interactions/blob/master/R/interact_plot.R) it shows that the final object is a `ggplot` object. Which is great, because you can modify "theme" of this object after it is plotted. You modify the theme and replot it et voila.

Since I'm on Windows and needed tips on how to modify font to TNY, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34528522/322912). Some of the examples in `interact_plot` didn't work for me, but I did manage to modify the one that did.

```
library(interactions)
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win")

fit <- lm(Income ~ HSGrad * Murder * Illiteracy, data = states)
xy <- interact_plot(model = fit, pred = Murder, modx = Illiteracy, mod2 = HSGrad)
xy + theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "serif"),
           legend.text = element_text(family = "serif"),
           legend.title = element_text(family = "serif"),
           strip.text = element_text(family = "serif"))
```

[image]