# corrplot: Changing to times new roman corrplot() output

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I've like to create an image using corrplot() function in corrplot package in times new roman without success. I try to use par(family="Times"), but doesn't work and in help of the function don't have font type control. I try to make:

```
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
## plot
par(family="Times")
corrplot(M, method = "number", col = "black", cl.pos = "n")
#
```

Please, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it will work but I think this post will help you :

[Changing fonts in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522732/changing-fonts-in-ggplot2)

It will not help you but it is a really good post on font for R so I leave it on my answer.

Are you on windows or unix ? If you are on windows this following answer will help you, if not I don't know.

The problem is just coming from the fact that you are using `Times` wherease it is `Times New Roman` needed.

You can check it with the following line of code :

```
windowsFonts()
par(family="Times New Roman")
corrplot(M, method = "number", col = "black", cl.pos = "n")
```

In fact TT is the first letter of TrueType and it is common for all fonts. If you want a specific font you should not use TT. See :

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/windowsFonts.html

Comment: Doen't work, when I make:                                                              
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win")
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
## plot
corrplot(M, method = "number", col = "black", cl.pos = "n", family="TT Times New Roman")
#

Comment: The code above alone on my windows computer works and you ?

Answer (score 1):

use "serif" rather than "Times" or a specific font for `par()`.
The function `corrplot` from package "corrplot" uses `graphics::text()` to add text to the plot. `?graphics::text` gives `...: further graphical parameters (from par), such as srt, family and xpd. These default to the values of the global graphical parameters in par()`.
So as mentioned, you can use `par(family)`.
`?windowsFonts` gives the documention: "The font family sent to the device is a simple string name, which must be mapped to something more specific to windows fonts." And "serif" is for a serif font——"TT Times New Roman" as seen with `windowsFonts()`. You may learn more from `?windowsFonts`.

```
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
par(family="serif")
corrplot(M, method = "number", col = "black", cl.pos = "n")
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**