# How to change font of ggplot into Times New Roman (on OS X)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple plot built with `ggplot`, however I want to change the font in the displayed plot simply into Times New Roman, size 12.

Here is an example of my code:

```
Kind <- c("Blue", "Green", "Red")
Date <- c("1 Day", "2 Days", "3 Days")
tStat <- c(4.3, 5.3, 1.4)

df <- data.frame(Kind, Date, tStat)

plot <- ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = tStat, color = Kind)) +
  facet_wrap(~Kind, ncol = 6) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = Date) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I found some tips on how to download fonts for windows via the package `extrafont` but that seems a bit extreme - is there no easy way to change it to Times?

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522732/changing-fonts-in-ggplot2

Comment: `extrafont` is a good way to go. `showtext` is another good option (in another answer at one of the duplicates).