# Using sysfonts from Google in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-webfonts

I am trying to figure out how to add Google Fonts to a ggplot2 with the `sysfonts` package (or another method). I am can them easily enough with `extrafont` but does anyone have a workflow to add them with `sysfonts`? Below is what I have so far:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
#> Registering fonts with R
#font_import() ## takes a while to run
loadfonts(device = "win")
#> Agency FB already registered with windowsFonts().
#> Algerian already registered with windowsFonts().
...
#> Vivaldi already registered with windowsFonts().
#> Vladimir Script already registered with windowsFonts().
#> Webdings already registered with windowsFonts().
#> Wingdings already registered with windowsFonts().
#> Wingdings 2 already registered with windowsFonts().
#> Wingdings 3 already registered with windowsFonts().


ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="Lucida Console"))
```

[image]

```r
library(sysfonts)
font_add_google('Yanone Kaffeesatz')

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="Yanone Kaffeesatz"))
#> Warning in grid.Call(C_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)): font family not
#> found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)): font family not
#> found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)): font family not
#> found in Windows font database
#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database
#> Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database
#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Obviously the 2nd plot wasn't created with the google font. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out [`showtext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906008/786542)