# Single function to download + install + import a font (e.g. for use in RMarkdown/ggplot) without needing to leave R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, extrafont

There are many tutorials on how to download and install fonts and use them in R (e.g. [here](https://rpubs.com/gbonafe/ggplot2-font), [here](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html), [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svglite/vignettes/fonts.html))

There seems to be a high degree of variety in the patterns used in these tutorials and others. Some use external packages, many require the user to open the browser, navigate to a font website, download a font file manually, and figure out where it needs to be placed in order for R to access it.

#### Question

Is there a single R function that allows you to run code that uses a font you **do not** yet have installed seamlessly without having to leave R?

#### Example

A real use case could look like this:

```
obscure_font <- "Manthul" # From: https://www.download-free-fonts.com/list/m/page-5
download_install_import_font(obscure_font)
qplot(1:10)+theme(text=element_text(family=obscure_font))
# Works immediately
```

#### What I know so far

I do not know of any such function, but my guess is that one ***could*** exist that

- accepts a font name as an argument
- `download.file()` for that font from an external website
- finds the appropriate location for it based on `Sys.info()$sysname`
- does anything else necessary so that the user can immediately use the font (e.g. unzips)
- imports the font into R

The acid test would be that someone could copy your RMarkdown/ggplot code containing an obscure font, and run it on their computer and it would 'just work'.

Comment: I don't know of any other font importing package, but I think `extrafont` is already pretty good ... You could write your own function, wrapping all the extrafont steps together!!

Comment: @stevec: check out [`showtext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906008/786542). It might have the function you need