# Change font family of stat_compare_mean() output in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-family

Is it possible to change the font family of the p-value in the following ggpboxplot? The font family should be "Times New Roman".

Using theme_bw(base_family = "Times New Roman"), does not change the p-value.

```
library(ggpubr) 
library(ggplot2)
data("ToothGrowth")

# Box plot 
p <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len",
      color = "supp", palette = "jco",
      add = "jitter",
      facet.by = "dose", short.panel.labs = FALSE) 

p + stat_compare_means(label = "p.format")
p + theme_bw(base_family = "Times New Roman")
```

I also tried it with normal theme(text = ...). It does not work.

```
# Box plot 
p <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len",
      color = "supp", palette = "jco",
      add = "jitter",
      facet.by = "dose", short.panel.labs = FALSE) 

p + stat_compare_means(label = "p.format")
p + theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"))
```

Please note: I took the example from the following website:
https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_compare_means.html

Thank you very, very much!

All the best,
Aenna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, the `family =` argument goes directly in `stat_compare_means()`.

From `help(stat_compare_means)`:

```
Usage
stat_compare_means(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, method = NULL,
  paired = FALSE, method.args = list(), ref.group = NULL,
  comparisons = NULL, hide.ns = FALSE, label.sep = ", ",
  label = NULL, label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = "top",
  label.x = NULL, label.y = NULL, tip.length = 0.03,
  bracket.size = 0.3, step.increase = 0, symnum.args = list(),
  geom = "text", position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...)
<snip>
...   other arguments to pass to geom_text or geom_label.
```

Thus, this code should do what you want.

```
 ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len",
      color = "supp", palette = "jco",
      add = "jitter",
      facet.by = "dose", short.panel.labs = FALSE) +
      stat_compare_means(label = "p.format",family = "Times New Roman") 
      #Use this if on Windows:  stat_compare_means(label = "p.format",family = "TT Times New Roman")
```

[image]

Comment: Note: you may need to [consult here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522732/changing-fonts-in-ggplot2) like I did when I received error message that "font family not found in Windows font database" (Obviously, I'm on a Windows PC).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I edited that into the answer.