# stat_compare_means(): Unable to change font family when using comparisons() argument?

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-family

I am following up on this question here [Change font family of stat_compare_mean() output in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123450/change-font-family-of-stat-compare-mean-output-in-ggplot). I am new here and didnt want to reply to the orginal question as i didnt know if it was the correct thing to do! Hope this is ok...

Below, I am also trying to use Times New Roman font in the `stat_compare_means()` function in ggplot. I am on a Windows computer so I am setting `Family = "Serif"`. I want to use the `comparisons` argument so I have the brackets etc. making it consistent with some previous work. However, when using the `comparisons` argument, it seems to overule the `family` argument and I am unable to change the font of the p value (if i comment out the `comparisons` argument, I am able to change the font). I have also tried setting the font in `theme(text = element_text(family = "serif"))`. This changes the font of everything to Times New Roman in the plot, apart from the `stat_compare_means()` output. Code that I used is below:

```
    ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len",
              color = "supp", palette = "jco",
              add = "jitter",
              facet.by = "dose", 
              short.panel.labs = FALSE) +
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("OJ", "VC")),
                       label = "p.format",
                       family = "serif",
                       size = 5)
```

Can anyone help please? Thank you.

SessionInfo:
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug (or at least an instance of unhandled user input) in `stat_compare_means`. It comes from the `...` parameters not being passed to `geom_signif` when comparisons are used. We can demonstrate this by creating a local version of `stat_compare_means` which is 'fixed' so that the `...` are passed when comparisons are used:

```r
fixed_call <- quote(ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = comparisons, 
                                          y_position = label.y, 
                      test = method, test.args = method.args, 
                      step_increase = step.increase, 
                      size = bracket.size, textsize = 5, color = color, 
                      map_signif_level = map_signif_level, 
                      tip_length = tip.length, data = data,
                      vjust = vjust, ...))

scm <- as.list(ggpubr::stat_compare_means)
scm[[26]][[2]][[3]][[13]] <- fixed_call
stat_compare_means <- function(...) {
  ggp <- getNamespace('ggpubr')
  .method_info <- ggp$.method_info
  .add_item <- ggp$.add_item
  .is_p.signif_in_mapping <- ggp$.is_p.signif_in_mapping
  .is_empty <- ggp$.is_empty
  do.call(as.function(scm), list(...), quote = FALSE)
}
```

Now we get:

```r
ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len",
          color = "supp", palette = "jco",
          add = "jitter",
          facet.by = "dose", 
          short.panel.labs = FALSE) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("OJ", "VC")),
                     label = "p.format", family = 'serif')
```

[image]

I'm not sure whether this is just an oversight by the authors or whether there were too many parameter name clashes to safely include `...` in this call, but it might be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: Hi Allan, Thank you for this! I will file a bug report. Cheers.