# Font adjustment issue with stat_compare_means() in ggplot2 revisited: "paint" the text manually?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, boxplot, showtext

This is a follow-up to [another user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77346644/stat-compare-means-unable-to-change-font-family-when-using-comparisons-argu). The inability to change font when the `comparisons()` argument is used is a known limitation of `stat_compare_means()`.

That initial issue is depicted in the MWE below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr) 
library(showtext)
tooth <- subset(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5)
font_add_google("Libre Baskerville")
showtext_auto()

ggboxplot(tooth, x = "supp", y = "len")+
  theme_classic(base_size = 20, base_family = "Libre Baskerville") +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("OJ", "VC")),
                     label = "p.format",
                     family = "Libre Baskerville",
                     size = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-14 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I attempted to address this issue by manually adding a `geom_rect()` object over the text produced by `stat_compare_means()`, intending to later add text with the desired font manually. However, the comparison bracket keeps "escaping away".

I want to remove the text with the wrong font while keeping the comparison bracket in place.

```r
ggboxplot(tooth, x = "supp", y = "len")+
  theme_classic(base_size = 20, base_family = "Libre Baskerville") +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("OJ", "VC")),
                     label = "p.format",
                     family = "Libre Baskerville",
                     size = 5) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = 23, ymax = 26), fill = "white",
           linetype = "dashed", color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-14 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simpler way round this.

First, create your plot:

```r
p <- ggboxplot(tooth, x = "supp", y = "len")+
  theme_classic(base_size = 20, base_family = "Libre Baskerville") +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("OJ", "VC")),
                     label = "p.format",
                     family = "Libre Baskerville",
                     size = 5)
```

Now write the family name directly into the `aes_parameters` of the second layer

```r
p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$family <- "Libre Baskerville"
```

Now the p value has your chosen font:

```r
p
```

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect workaround! Many thanks indeed - I will use this solution extensively. Btw: is there a similar workaround to raise that text's y coordinate away from the bracket by a few pixels - or should that question be asked in another "ticket" in SO?