# "EB Garamond" font in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I'm following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906008/11570343) but it doesn't work. How can I change to "EB Garamont 12" font?

```
library(showtext)
library(ggplot2)
font_files()
windows()
font_add_google("EB Garamond")
font_families()
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 20, base_family = "EB Garamond" )) +
  annotate("text", 1, 11, label = 'GGTT', hjust = 0,
           family = myFont2, size = 10) 
print(a)
```

[image]

I also did this using `font_import(paths = NULL, recursive = TRUE, prompt = TRUE,pattern = NULL)` but nowhere do I see the `EB Garamond` family.

[image]

```
font_import(paths = NULL, recursive = TRUE, prompt = TRUE,pattern = NULL)

#Scanning ttf files in C:\WINDOWS\Fonts ...
#Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
#C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf : ArialMT already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#...
#...
#C:\Windows\Fonts\ebrima.ttf : Ebrima already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\ebrimabd.ttf : Ebrima-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\euclid.ttf : Euclid already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\euclidb.ttf : Euclid-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\euclidbi.ttf : Euclid-BoldItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\euclidi.ttf : Euclid-Italic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eucsym.ttf : EuclidSymbol already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eucsymb.ttf : EuclidSymbol-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eucsymbi.ttf : EuclidSymbol-BoldItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eucsymi.ttf : EuclidSymbol-Italic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\euextra.ttf : EuclidExtra already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\euextrab.ttf : EuclidExtra-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eufrak.ttf : EuclidFraktur already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eufrakb.ttf : EuclidFraktur-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eumat1.ttf : EuclidMathOne already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eumat1b.ttf : EuclidMathOne-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eumat2.ttf : EuclidMathTwo already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\eumat2b.ttf : EuclidMathTwo-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\fences.ttf : Fences-Plain already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#C:\Windows\Fonts\framd.ttf : FranklinGothic-Medium already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
#...

extrafont::loadfonts(device="win") #I can't find EB Garamond
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `showtext_auto()` before plotting.

```r
library(showtext)
library(ggplot2)

font_add_google("EB Garamond")
windows()

showtext_auto()

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 20, base_family = "EB Garamond" )) +
  annotate("text", 1, 11, label = 'GGTT', hjust = 0,
           family = "EB Garamond", size = 10)
```

The windows device now shows:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize that function, thx. And how could I load the font `EB Garamond 12 ALL SC` from my computer (the one in the image)?.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to follow this answer but when I run windows(), I get Error in windows() : could not find function "windows", what is the package that needs to be installed for this function? I am using R studio in a Mac.