# Is there a way to manually set font family in Qgraph plot?

Tags: r, networking, layout, fonts, data-visualization

I am currently working on a network analysis in Qgraph. Because of some procedural requirements, node labels, legend as well as title should be in a specific font. Is there a way to manually set this to any font? (Not referring to the label.font = {1, 2...} argument that changes italics, bold, ...

Comment: check out the first answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522732/changing-fonts-in-ggplot2

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: mh, people might help more if you posted a minimal example, what you tried and what error you get.